# go error on doing HTTP requests

Tags: go

When running the following http client to stress test a web server, got strange error, wonder what was the cause.  The version of go is `go1.8.1 linux/amd64` running on Ubuntu 14.04 with 16GB of ram.

```
$ go run te2.go 
563.904492ms
Get http://10.3.0.6/small: dial tcp 10.3.0.6:80: connect: cannot assign requested address
Get http://10.3.0.6/small: dial tcp 10.3.0.6:80: connect: cannot assign requested address
Get http://10.3.0.6/small: dial tcp 10.3.0.6:80: connect: cannot assign requested address
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x40 pc=0x5e3b27]

goroutine 140284 [running]:
main.httpGet(0x0)
    /home/jon/learn/go/te2.go:27 +0x107
created by main.main
    /home/jon/learn/go/te2.go:45 +0xd3
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x40 pc=0x5e3b27]

goroutine 140375 [running]:
main.httpGet(0x0)
    /home/jon/learn/go/te2.go:27 +0x107
created by main.main
    /home/jon/learn/go/te2.go:45 +0xd3
exit status 2
```

any ideas?

Here is the code snippet:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "bufio"
import "os"
import "time"
import "net/http"

var req = []byte("GET /small HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
"Host: localhost\r\n" +
"Content-Length: 0\r\n\r\n");
var buf = make([]byte, 1024)
var total = 0;
var t0 = time.Now()
var c = make(chan int)

func httpGet ()  int {
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "http://10.3.0.6/small", nil)
    //req.Header.Add("User-Agent", `MYCLIENT`)
    //req.Header.Add("Cookie", `sessid=12345`)
    client := &http.Client{}
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    //defer resp.Body.Close()
    if (err != nil) {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    resp.Body.Close()
    total ++
    if (total == 10000) {
        fmt.Println(time.Now().Sub(t0))
    }
    c <- 1
    return 0;
}

func main() {
    i := 1
    t0 = time.Now()
    for (i < 1000) {
        go httpGet()
        i += 1
    }
    for (1 < 2) {
        <-c
        go httpGet()
    }
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    text, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
    fmt.Println(text)   
}
```

Comment: Irrelevant: there is a data race on the `total` variable. Use `atomic.AddInt32`

Comment: Below answer is correct for the panic. The other message `connect: cannot assign requested address` I believe is due to running out of ports to use to make requests on.

Comment: @zerkms, thanks for the good point of using `atomic.AddInt32`, it makes perfect sense.

Comment: Thanks @Adrian for the tip, I set the `ip_local_port_range`  but it didn't help much. But after setting `conn.(*net.TCPConn).SetLinger(0)`, it helped. I guess the difference is that setting linger option to be 0 will force TCP session to reset at the end instead of nature timeout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
resp, err := client.Do(req)
//defer resp.Body.Close()
if (err != nil) {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
resp.Body.Close()
```

In this fragment you're checking the `err` and continue execution.

So if something happened and the `err` is not `nil`, but `resp` is (or the `resp.Body` is) - you print the error then dereference a nil pointer.

What you should have done: if an error occurs - cleanup and return from the function.